# Using PYTHONPATH to use a virtualenv

Tags: python

I have a virtualenv in a structure like this:

venv/
  src/
    project_files

I want to run a makefile (which calls out to Python) in the project_files, but I want to run it from a virtual environment. Because of the way my deployment orchestration works, I can't simply do a source venv/bin/activate.

Instead, I've tried to `export PYTHONPATH={project_path}/venv/bin/python2.7`. When I try to run the makefile, however, the python scripts aren't finding the dependencies installed in the virtualenv. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Activate the virtualenv, and have a look at the PYTHONPATH that it gives you.

Answer (score 0):

The `PYTHONPATH` environmenbt variable is not used to select the path of the Python executable - which executable is selected depends, as in all other cases, on the shell's `PATH` environment variable. `PYTHONPATH` is used to augment the search list of directories (`sys.path` in Python) in which Python will look for modules to satisfy imports.

Since the interpreter puts certain directories on `sys.path` before it actions `PYTHONPATH` precisely to ensure that replacement modules with standard names do not shadow the standard library names. So any standard library module will be imported from the library associated with the interpreter it was installed with (unless you do some manual furkling, which I wouldn't recommend).

`venv/bin/activate` does a lot of stuff that needs to be handled in the calling shell's namespace, which can make tailoring code rather difficult if you can't find a way to source the script..

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just call the Python interpreter in your virtual environment. So, in your Makefile, instead of calling `python`, call `venv/bin/python`.

Answer (score 0):

To run a command in a virtualenv, you could use [`vex` utility](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vex):

```
$ vex venv make
```

You could also check, whether `make PYTHON=venv/bin/python` would be enough in your case.

`PYTHONPATH` adjusts `sys.path` list. It doesn't change `python` binary. Don't use it here.